# Docker: Volume mounts crash container on windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I'm running two container, one for the backend and one for the frontend, for my application. The os of my host machine is windows 10.

Both container used to mount their source code in order to enable hot reload while the container are up. This worked perfectly fine till now.
But since the 8th june 2023 that volume mounts cause the container to crash. This happend nearly out of nowhere with no particular reason for the problem.

While mounting the volumes the container crash right away. E.g. the backend container shows this error message "exec ./docker_intern.sh: input/output error".
I've read, that this could be caused by a corrupted file system. This would align with the volume mounts being the cause of the problem.

My question is: Why did this happen so suddenly and how can i fix it?

PS: Going back to past commits of my application didn't help. So it seems, that the problem has something to do with docker+windows itself.